# Cakephp: creating a not enforced table/model relationship

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new to cakephp and
I can't seem to get the relationship right in the following scenario:

I have a database with 2 tables, clients and events. Clients can have many events, events belongs to one client, but sometimes events don't belong to a client, or the client detail is not known when the event needs to be entered.

Is there a way to have cakephp not enforce a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't matter. If you do a Event->find( ... ) and there is no linked Client the results will simply have an empty 'Client' => array( ) in the returned results.

As for not entering a client, make sure you can select an empty option in the drop-down where you would select a client for the event. Also, make sure the field allows validation to pass when you try and save a blank client_id.

Nothing tricky here - the basics will work just fine for you out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you are right, but i don't know how to add/allow a blank client in the drop down list. I will appreciate if you could give me the code.

Comment: the html helper that generates the drop down looks like this: `$this->Form->input('client_id');`. How do i alter it to add a blank entry?

Comment: Answer: 
`$this->Form->input('client_id', array('empty' => 'Choose one')`